# Flexbox that goes full width when forced onto new line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have two divs lined next to each other using the following CSS:

```
.overlay {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;   
}

.mainContent {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  margin: 5px;
}

.interactions {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 5px; 
}
```

When the width of the screen gets too small (i.e. .interactions can no longer fit) a new row is created in which interactions are placed.

What I'd like to do when that happens is for interactions to switch to max-width: 100%, is there any way to do this without using javascript?

Comment: show you html please

Comment: BTW it break line because `flex-wrap: wrap;`:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Comment: The CSS you posted already works that way -- what's the problem? Whenever the content does not fit, the `.interactions` element ends up on its own line, occupying entire width of the parent box.

Comment: @amn "What I'd like to do when that happens is for interactions to switch to max-width: 100%, is there any way to do this without using javascript?"

Comment: I still do not understand. `.interactions` _will_ occupy the entire width of the flex container, when wrapped on its own line, with your CSS. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There's two situations here

> screen gets too small

1. if screen goes below 400px we're okay with the rules so far
2. if screen is above 400px but still too small, we end up with conflicting max-widths

> is there anyway to do this without using javascript?

It can be achieved with media queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .instructions { min-width: 100% }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that works on window width not the elements width

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should use media queries?

```
@media (max-width: 400px) { 
  .interactions {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that works on window width not the elements width

Comment: please, paste your all code, maybe then i can help you more.

Comment: @tweetypi You talk in your question about screen size, this solution should fix the issue's you have. And if it doesn't, rewrite your question and include all code so we might have a better look at the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using media queries is a challenge here because the breakpoint at which the problem occurs is dependent on the size of the flexible width .mainContent

So a better approach would be to have a min-width on .mainContent and use a media query for the breakpoint which is a sum of the min-width of .mainContent and max-width of .interactions + margins

```
.overlay {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:stretch;
}
.mainContent {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    min-width:400px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.interactions {
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width:400px;
    margin: 5px; 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 840px){
    .mainContent, .interactions{
        max-width:none;
        min-width:none;
    }
}
```

See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/gnu12Lfs/

Answer (score -1):

you shuld to use the nowrap property,
the flex-wrap: wrap create new line when the intenrnal divs are too little, the nowrap not create, the code to remain in the same line is

```
.overlay {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;

  }
  .mainContent {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    margin: 5px;
  }

  .interactions {
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 5px; 
  }
```

you can find the documentation here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-wrap.asp

Also you can find other details of the usage and the browser compatibility here https://caniuse.com/#search=flex-wrap